# Indentar código no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como criar um atalho para deixar os espaços iguais entre atribuições?

Ex:

```
$nome = "Maria Ferreira";
$telefone = "99645876";
```

Para

```
$nome     = "Maria Ferreira";
$telefone = "99645876";
```

Comment: [E no Visual Studio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383551/indentar-verticalmente-c%c3%b3digo-no-visual-studio)

Comment: Lista dos atalho do Visual Code: [Window](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf), [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) e [MacOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Nativamente desconheço atalho que faça isso.

Mas eu uso a **extensão `Better Align`** que faz exatamente isso e vc pode configurar no teclado o atalho que quiser. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align

Vai em `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` E cria seu atalho assim por exemplo:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+i",  "command": "wwm.aligncode",
                           "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*No link acima tem a documentação completa.*

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo.

Comment: @Herick legal que bom que resolveu ai, tmj! Se vc quiser um atalho nativo mas que faz apenas uma identação simples das tags tenta (Ctrl+K Ctrl+F), mas ele só identa as tag, não alinha e gera os espaço como na extensão ok.

Comment: só a respeito de curiosidade é indicado identar desse jeito ou por alguns é considerado má formatação do código ?

Comment: @luizricardo6n até onde eu sei isso é questão de gosto mesmo. Tem gente que acha o código mais "legível" quando indentado dessa forma, mas não que isso seja regra, pode ser que na sua equipe possa ser uma "boa prática", mas na equipe de outra empresa pode não ser usado... No Guia do próprio Google por exemplo eles não indentam CSS ou HTML dessa forma... https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html

Comment: Ok, obrigado ai por esclarecer.

Answer (score 18):

Para indentar o código, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Este é o comando padrão!

Answer (score 7):

Segundo o Key Bindings, no windows você usa <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

No Mac é <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

E no Linux é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Caso queira customizar, siga estes passos: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_customizing-shortcuts

Fonte: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2017 (Windows) ==>  Ctrl + K + D para identar automáticamente

Comment: A pergunta foi feita em relação ao Visual Studio Code e não Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

> Só para acrescentar com informação atualizada:
>  Para atualizar a
>   parte: `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly`, você deve clicar com o
>   botão direito do mouse sobre a linha e escolher a opção:
>   `Change When Expression` ou `Ctrl+K Ctrl+E` com a linha selecionada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Você também pode abrir o arquivo **keybindings.json**, na Paleta de
>   comandos *(Ctrl+Shift+P)*, pesquisar por *Preferences: Open Keyboard
>   Shortcuts (JSON)*, mas é somente leitura.

**REFERÊNCIA:**

1. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules

Comment: Cara não entendi o que vc quis dizer com isso? Como isso ai funciona? Aqui não serviu pra nada....

Answer (score -2):

Os comandos podem mudar dependendo da versão do *vscode*; logo, para saber o comando, acesse *File* > *Preferences* > *Keyboard Shortcuts* e consulte. Se não funcionar, tente indentar com este comando: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>