# Indentar verticalmente código no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Em complementação a [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317037/indentar-c%C3%B3digo-no-visual-studio-code/), venho aqui perguntar: como faço o mesmo processo na **IDE do Visual Studio**? (isso não vale pro Code!) Visto que, automaticamente ele transforma disso:

```cs
var small_var        = "hello, world!";
var big_named_var    = "foo, bar";
```

para isso:

```cs
var small_var = "hello, world!";
var big_named_var = "foo, bar";
```

Existe alguma maneira de tornar igual o primeiro trecho sempre?

> De preferência, especifique em que versão do Visual Studio funciona. Isso vale tanto para o 2015, 2017 e **2019**.

Comment: Coloca uma tag `!code`

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS aquela pergunta é para *Visual Studio Code*, essa é de *Visual Studio*. Existe diferença entre ambos. Eu citei isso na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A extensão Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 tem a função de Align Assignments, que realiza o que você precisa.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017

> Aligns assignment statements by typing Ctrl+Alt+].
>
> Note! This may conflict with your formatting settings. E.g. in C# you
>   will need to disable: Tools->Options->Text
>   Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration
>   statements"

Comment: A resposta não é o link, mas é essa opção: `E.g. in C# you will need to disable: Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration statements"`.

Answer (score 0):

Existe a própria edentação do VS, clicando com o botão direito e selecionando **"Format Document"**, outra forma é pressionando :

> "ALT + SHIFT + F"

. Nenhuma dessas opções te atende?
Se não atender dê uma olhada no link :
[Better Align- Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align)

Comment: Isso me abriu o menu de ferramentas...

Comment: Mas nenhuma delas faz o AP especifica na pergunta, certo?