# Correção Visual Studio

Tags: react, visual-studio

Como corrigir essa formatação?

Exemplo, uso visual Studio e tudo que estou escrevendo está sendo separado dessa forma:

```
function Menu() {
    return ( <
        header > Revista < /header>
    );
}
```

De nenhuma forma eles estão juntando. Antes estava dando "complexity is 3 everything" mas retirei isso.
É uma pergunta boba só que realmente não faço ideia do que está ativado para ficar dando isso.

Comment: Você pode usar o [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) para formatação

Comment: Pro Visual Studio, a extensão é https://github.com/madskristensen/JavaScriptPrettier . Pro VSCode, só pesquisar nas extensões por "prettier".

Comment: Você provavelmente tem a extensão beautify instalada. Desabilite e seja feliz

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo da linguagem que você estiver usando, você pode baixar algum plugin de Code Formatter pra linguagem especifica que for usar.
Basta procurar na galeria de extensões do VS Code: "SuaLinguagem Formatter".
Basta clicar em algum local do documento e apertar alt+shift+F.

Tem algo assim também: [VSCode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317037/indentar-c%C3%B3digo-no-visual-studio-code)