# Inserção em modo coluna no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Bom dia!
No modo coluna do Visual Studio Code, ativado ou pelo botão do meio do mouse ou pela combinação com a tecla Alt, como consigo inserir algo em todas as linhas, porém numa mesma coluna?
Por exemplo: Tenho as seguintes linhas abaixo:

```
São Paulo
Campinas
São José dos Campos
Santos
Piracicaba
```

então quero inserir, neste exemplo, o literal "SP" em uma coluna à frente dos nomes das cidades, assim:

```
São Paulo            SP
Campinas             SP
São José dos Campos  SP
Santos               SP
Piracicaba           SP
```

Eu ainda não encontrei esta facilidade. Ele sempre insere ao final de cada linha, ficando:

```
São PauloSP
CampinasSP
São José dos CamposSP
SantosSP
PiracicabaSP
```

Outro detalhe: Eu nem sempre insiro informação por simples digitação. Eu colo a informação da área de trabalho. Então, se SEMPRE eu precisar marcar a coluna em todas as n-linhas, isto se tornará contraproducente, visto que poderei ter situações com milhares de linhas.

Veja animação da função em ação no editor UltraEdit da IDM:
[image: Inserção em coluna com [CTRL+V]]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Indentar código no Visual Studio Code](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317037/indentar-c%c3%b3digo-no-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Não é indentação, pois isto depende do tipo de arquivo.
O que procuro é uma fácil maneira de inserir dados (colando ou digitando) em determinada coluna para todas as linhas selecionadas. Seria um texto tabulado.

Comment: olha ai https://imgur.com/a/axymMx9

Comment: Bom dia, hugocsl!
Hoje faço isto mesmo. Para poucas linhas é adequado e eficiente, porém posso ter situações que insiro milhares de linhas. Mais um detalhe que eu originalmente não indiquei: Eu quero colar informação naquela coluna.
Já imaginou eu ter que selecionar sempre todas as n-linhas?
Eu gostaria de clicar numa coluna e aplicar a colagem do SO (o popular Ctrl+V).

Answer (score 0):

Isso não funciona no VSCode! (ainda)

Para utilizar essa funcionalidade é necessário que o VSCode disponibilize a opção de "Virtual Spaces" que ainda não foi implementada.

Esse problema ja foi reportado há um bom tempo e tem algumas discussões ativas nos problemas reportados aos desenvolvedores (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960 ) , mas parece que ainda sem previsão de solução. :(

Answer (score -1):

O que faz existir uma coluna em um arquivo de texto puro é o espaçamento. Nesse caso aí, não é tão simples deixar exatamente igual, mas pode fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de selecionado todo o texto, seguro `CTRL+ALT+I` para entrar no modo de edição em todas as linhas.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui ;) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317037/indentar-c%c3%b3digo-no-visual-studio-code/317039#317039

Comment: Bom dia, David!
Isto eu já faço, porém em muitas situações a quantidade de linhas é de milhares e esta técnica é trabalhosa e ineficiente. Eu costumo inserir vários espaços/tabulações, depois marco a coluna  que quero (no modo coluna) em todas as linhas usando Alt ou botão central do mouse, insiro um símbolo, que normalmente o ponto-e-vírgula, depois começo a trocar todas as ocorrências de ponto-e-virgula e uma espaço, por apenas ponto-e-vírgula até extingui-las. Por fim, elimino os ponto-e-vírgula iniciais.

continua...

Comment: ...continuando:
Outro editor que uso bastante é o UltraEdit da IDM. Ele tem esta função e é por isso que eu gostaria de encontrar uma maneira semelhante de implementá-la no VSC. Já procurei por extensões e não achei nada parecido ainda.

Comment: A solução do @hugocsl parece resolver muito bem, valeu!

Comment: Porém para situações envolvendo milhares de linhas é trabalhoso.
Lido com muitas importações de dados desestruturados e essa caraterística é essencial para o desempenho das minhas tarefas.
Tenho outros meios que utiliza, como a combinação de software (UltraEdit da IDM) com o VSC. E no VCS uso Python para manipular os dados, mas ... preciso dispor um mínimo de estrutura de dados em texto, pois visualmente é mais rápido.

Answer (score -3):

Resolvido com essa extensão !

Nome: Column Paste
ID: johnguo.columnpaste
Descrição: Copy/Paste a column text
Versão: 0.0.7
Editor: John Guo
Link do Marketplace do VS: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnguo.columnpaste

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).